# CPPUNIT: common base test

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-studio-2008, cppunit

I would like to know an efficient design or implementation for testing base classes.
Given the example:

```
class Polygon;
class Rectangle : public Polygon;
class Triangle : public Polygon;
```

Where `Rectangle` and `Triangle` inherit from `Polygon`.

I would like to have the test classes for `Rectangle` and `Triangle` use a base testing class:

```
class Test_Rectangle : public CppUnit::TestFixture;
class Test_Triangle : public CppUnit::TestFixture;
```

But I don't know if the `class Test_Polygon` should inherit from `CppUnit::TestFixture`.

My present plan is:
    class Test_Polygon;
    class Test_Rectangle : public Test_Polygon, public CppUnit::TestFixture;
    class Test_Triangle : public Test_Polygon, public CppUnit::TestFixture;

The issue with the above plan is that `Test_Polygon` can't use `CPPUNIT_ASSERT` nor will its methods be listed in the CPPUNIT registry.

So what is the recommended hierarchy for testing base classes and descendants using CPPUNIT?

*(I'm using CPPUNIT 1.12 with Visual Studio 2008 on Windows Vista.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer depends on whether or not Polygon is a virtual base class.  If it's virtual, then I would treat it as a "private" class and I wouldn't directly test it, and wouldn't need a Test_Polygon at all.  Unit testing each of the subclasses should provide all the information of whether it functions properly or not.

If you are testing a method that's implemented in the base class, you could test it from any class that doesn't override it.  If it's a method that's called from within your subclass, like `Rectangle::SetSideLen(int len) { return Polygon::SetSideLen(len); };` then the testing should be accomplished by testing testRectangle.SetSideLen() in Test_Rectangle.  And if you have no classes that don't override it, your base class is essentially unreachable code that probably should be removed.

If you can actually instantiate a stand-alone Polygon, then I would treat it like it's "public", so I would have Test_Polygon inherit from TestFixture in order to test those public methods.